# Leaflet map image path

Tags: webpack, leaflet, vue.js

I use leaflet maps in my vue.js project and can't set imagePath correctly.
I've created assets folder where I store needed leaflet images but I always get 404 errors.

```
L.Icon.Default.imagePath = 'assets/vendor/leaflet'
```

I think it is a webpack configuration issue. 
How can I configure webpack to make it work properly?

Comment: Yeah, It's probably webpack issue, or proabably your path is not correct.Without you project structure we can't tell a lot.
Did you tried this `L.Icon.Default.imagePath = '../assets/vendor/leaflet'`

Comment: @BelminBedak I tried making it relative but it seems that lib tries to make http request to the endpoint that doesn't exist.

http://localhost:8080/assets/vendor/leaflet/marker-icon-2x.png - 404

Answer (score 0):

do you have a file named `marker-icon-2x.png` ? generally `2x` file is not present in the folder.